# fetching data from kinvey causing app crash

Tags: android, kinvey

I am making an android app and fetching data from kinvey. It is creating users and logging them in but when i try to fetch data from kinvey then app got crashed.
here ismy entity class:

[image: Entity class]

Here is the kinvey Collection for my app:

[image: Kinvey collection]

and finally here is my code in main class from where i am try to fetch data:

[image]

and here is the catlog in order you want to see error

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you get a `NullPointerException`.
From the StackTrace: you are calling `result.length` in your `onSucess()` method but the `result` variable is `null`.
You should verify it is not null before trying to do anything with this object.